# react bootstrap table button conflict with row clicking

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I started working with React and all of the ported libraries that bootstrap have and the custom ones.

Currently I'm having and issue with react bootstrap table: I have defined that when a user clicks on a row it shows a panel to edit that row, but I also have a button in one of the rows column, so when I click the button, the button is clicked but then the onRowClick event is triggered to and I don't want that  to happen, I tried a lot of different ways but I couldn't make it work, do you have any idea how.

This is the table:

```
<BootstrapTable 
                data = { this.props.data }
                striped = { true }
                hover = { true }
                search = { true }
                options = {{ onRowClick: this.props.onUserEdit } } >

                <TableHeaderColumn 
                    dataField = "id"
                    isKey = { true }
                    dataSort = { true }
                    hidden = { true }> ID 
                </TableHeaderColumn> 

                <TableHeaderColumn 
                    dataField = "email"         
                    dataAlign="center"
                    dataSort = { true }> Email 
                </TableHeaderColumn> 

                <TableHeaderColumn 
                    dataField = "name"
                    dataAlign="center"
                    dataSort = { true }> User Name 
                </TableHeaderColumn> 

                <TableHeaderColumn 
                    dataField = "info"
                    dataAlign="center"
                    dataSort = { true }> Study, Site ID, Role 
                </TableHeaderColumn> 

                <TableHeaderColumn 
                    dataField = "lastlogin"
                    dataAlign="center"
                    dataSort = { true }
                    dataFormat={this.buttonFormatter}> Last Login 
                </TableHeaderColumn> 
</BootstrapTable>
```

This is how I render a button in the cell (this.echo is just a debug alert):

```
buttonFormatter: function(cell, row, formatExtraData, rowIdx) {
    return (<Button onClick={ this.echo } className="grid-button">{cell}</Button>);
},
```

The issue is when I hover the button, the row remains as on hover.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried stopping propagation of the event in the button onClick callback?

```
echo(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("echo");
},
```

Comment: I believe it should be `e.stopPropagation()` since you also mentioned in your answer above the code snippet.

Comment: I altered my flow, I now have a column with actions and a button there to do what I've done previously with row click, anyway, I'm gonna try your answer and give feedback, thanks!